# How to delete an item from a Linked List in Perl?

Tags: perl

I must be missing something in my implementation of remove item from a linked list in Perl.

The code below would remove all the nodes with value = 5.

But when I call `remove_fives([[[[[], 3], 5], 1]])`, it is deleting the last element, 3, instead of 5.

Any Help ?

```
sub remove_fives {
 my $list = shift;
 my $node = $list->[0];
 while ( $node->[0] ) {
    my $last = $node;
    ( $node, my $value ) = @$node;

    if ($value == 5) {
      $last->[0] = $node->[0];
    }
 }

 return $list;
}
```

This is my following code that I used to test:

```
sub list_str {
 my $list   = shift;
 my $result = '';
 my $node   = $list->[0];
 my $first  = 1;
 while ( $node->[0] ) {
    ( $node, my $value ) = @$node;

    if ( !$first ) {
        $result .= ';';
    }

    $result .= $value;
    $first = 0;
 }

 return $result;
}

my $list = [[[[[], 3], 5], 1]];
print "\n Original linked list: " . list_str($list);       # 1;5;3
print "\n After remove: " . list_str(remove_fives($list)); # 1;5
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output would be `[[[[], 3], 1]]`

Comment: The expected output for `list_str(remove_fives($list))` would be '1;3'

Comment: Why are you trying to implement a "linked list" in Perl? Linked lists are generally considered a low-level data structure; they aren't appropriate in a language which already has higher-level data structures as primitive types.

Comment: @duskwuff, Poppycock. It's not primitive. Simple, maybe, not primitive. It's just rarely needed. LL have the unusual property that deleting an item is O(1) (having previously found the item). In contrast, this would be O(N) for an array.

Comment: You know, because hashes totally aren't a thing

Comment: @ikegami The "primitives" I'm referring to are Perl's arrays and hashes - not in the sense that they are crude, but that they are basic language types. My point is that using an array to build a worse array is a bit circular. :)

Comment: @duskwuff, Tired. Pretend I said low-level instead of primitive.

Comment: @Chris Rasys, But hashes can't maintain an order like a LL can, so you can't necessarily replace a LL with a hash either.

Comment: The array can double the size with just a single push operation. This can be harmful in same cases. In contrast, a LL will always perform a push in  O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$last` points to the current node, and `$node` points to the next node.

`$last` should point to the previous node, and `$node` should point to the current node.

Conveniently, the list itself has the same format as a node, so we don't need [trickery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213449/589924).

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

sub remove_fives {
    my $list = shift;
    my $last = $list;
    while (1) {
        my $node = $last->[0];
        last if !$node;

        if ($node->[1] == 5) {
           $last->[0] = $node->[0];
        } else {
           $last = $node;
        }
    }
}

my $list = [[[[undef, 3], 5], 1]];
remove_fives($list);

local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
local $Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
print(Dumper($list), "\n");   # [[[undef,3],1]]
```

---

If the list didn't have the same format as a node, this is what the code would look like:

```
sub delete_node {
   my $node_ptr_ptr = shift;
   $$node_ptr_ptr = $$node_ptr_ptr->next;
}

sub remove_fives {
    my $list = shift;
    my $node_ptr_ptr = \( $list->{head} );
    while ($$node_ptr_ptr) {
        if ($$node_ptr_ptr->{val} == 5) {
           delete_node($$node_ptr_ptr);
        } else {
           $node_ptr_ptr = \( $$node_ptr_ptr->{next} );
        }
    }
}
```